# Magento how to disable gallery popup from moo cloud zoom

Tags: magento, cloud, zooming

i am using Magento Moo_CloudZoom plugin for product zoom feature. Base image is zooming out nicely.

But when you click on the base image product image gallery is open in the popup, i want to disable gallery images popup.
Can anyone help me how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to this location template\moo\catalog\product\view\media.phtml

comment the content of on line 63, this remove the notice of clicking on image

and than comment the content of line 69
i.e below one

```
$_img = '<img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
```

Comment: At last i figured it out myself. i had to change "cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js" file and popup is no more showing.

Comment: I did not get enough privileges to close this question. Can anyone close this question for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem ..

Go to .
skin/frontend/wc/default/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js and comment the following line in js file

```
$mouseTrap.unbind('click').bind('click', function() { var a = $(this).prev('a'); var l = a.attr('data-lightbox'); if (l != null) { a.trigger('click'); return; } var t = a.attr('gallery'); if (t == '') { return; } popWin(t, 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); });
```

This will retain the hover on the required image and disable the onclick event